# Fail to save all byte array to png picture by naming them with timestamp

Tags: c#, time, save, naming

I tried to save all blobs into png picture but when I named the png with current time stamp, it seem like the saving process has **timeout** and only success for the last blob. If I put 2 seconds delay, only it can save all.

`reportthread_image` is `List<byte[]>` of blob (in this case is 4 blobs) retrieved from mysql database.

```c#
foreach (byte[] rt_image in reportthread_image)
{
    if (rt_image.Count() != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            ms = new MemoryStream(rt_image);
            fullsizeImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
            bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            count++;
            //only can save last image without delay
            //Thread.Sleep(2000); //need long enough delay to save all
            //bm.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);//can save all blobs to png.
            bm.Save(count + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);//no error will occurs here.
            ms.Dispose();
            bm.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

May I know that how can I **save the image** with current timestamp and only proceed to next element **after finish** the **saving** process in the reportthread_image?
I tried lock(), I tried Invoked()

and I actually cannot understand

### why the process is not wait the save process finish only proceed to next line??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you overwrite your previous saved file. Include milliseconds in file name and be happy.

```
bm.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I think it is not good idea to sleep thread.
To be more accurate, you must use guaranteed changeable factor in your generated name, because `DateTame` hasn't enough accuracy. Something like this:

```
bm.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + count++ + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Then

Comment: Yes, you are right! I can save all files with delay more than 1 sec because their file name will definitely different in that scenario! thanks. take long time to solve this basic error....